# How sum byte array with for loop?

Tags: java

This works!
Array lenght is 8

```
int crc = (bin[1] + bin[2] + bin[3] + bin[4] + bin[5] + bin[6]) & 0Xff;
```

the problem is that receive data length may vary.
and i try calculate the checksum with loop, but i dont get it work.

```
byte crc = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < bin.length - 2; i++) {
   crc += bin[i];
}
int crcI = crc & 0xff;
```

this usually gives wrong values, but sometimes they are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This check:

```
i < bin.length - 2
```

evaluates to:

```
i < 8 - 2
```

ie

```
i < 6
```

ie the last element to be taken into account is at index `5`, not `6`.

If you are trying to get the sum of every byte except the first and the last one, then you should probably use:

```
for (int i = 1; i < bin.length - 1; i++) {
    ...
}
```

or, change your `<` operator to `<=`, like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= bin.length - 2; i++) {
    ...
}
```

An example when the result may be correct in the code you gave in your question is if the element at index `6` (ie `bin[6]`) is equal to `0` (and that's because `0` will not contribute to a sum).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I don't understand what i was thinking.
Honestly i was trying nearly hour figure what's wrong with code :)

Comment: Don't worry, those things happen. :)